# Python List of Paired Points, How to Find Points Along Line

Tags: python, list, lines

I have a set of functions that generate a list of paired points like this:

```
my_list=[((57.5, 3048.0), (62.0, 3050.0)), ((82.0, 1006.0), (93.0, 1021.5)), ((95.0, 1354.0), (86.0, 1336.0)), ((95.0, 1354.0), (89.0, 1327.0))...]
```

Such that each pair is:

```
((57.5, 3048.0), (62.0, 3050.0)) Pair 0
((82.0, 1006.0), (93.0, 1021.5)) Pair 1
((95.0, 1354.0), (86.0, 1336.0)) Pair 2
((95.0, 1354.0), (89.0, 1327.0)) Pair 3
((104.0, 2366.0), (109.0, 2350.0)) Pair 4
((104.0, 2370.0), (109.0, 2350.0)) Pair 5
((122.5, 2375.0), (109.0, 2350.0)) Pair 6
```

etc.

This is a long list of `X,Y` coordinates generated from analyzing images. I need to find a way to reject most of the points.

Anything less than 3 points that don't fall on a similar line (not exact, need some wiggle room) needs to be rejected.

Most of the points are clusters not on a line, or only two points on a line. Is there a way to run through this list and only save the set of 3 or more points on roughly the same line?

Here is an image to demonstrate what I'm after. The image shows the faint moving asteroid found by the functions and all of the noise also found. You can see the asteroid has 3 + points roughly on the same line while the noise is rather random. I am trying to discard the points that are only two points on the same line.

[image]

A lot to ask, but essential!

After implementing answer 1

[image]

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I wouldn't be here asking if I knew how to approach this.

Comment: So 2 Points define a line and you need any third point (or more) which is also on this line? Why not take 2 point get the slope and check wether any other point matches?

Comment: If 3 points are on a same line, their coordinates will verify :`(x1-x2)*(y1-y3)-(x1-x3)*(y1-y2)=0`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The points may not be exactly on the same line, but very close. If it is the object I'm after, they will also have roughly the same distance between the points and be on the same line. I am using the center of mass function to generate the list from a series of 4 images with moving objects in them. There will be a few thousand point pairs to work over. So I could look for two points within a certain distance from one another, solve the line for them, and see if any other points are on that line...

Comment: The points are given in pairs.Each point has an x and y coordinate. If pairs of points are (p1,p2), (p3,p4), etc, and p3 is not "near" the line from p1 to p2, do you reject only p3? or both p3 and p4?

Comment: Maybe you can get a regression line first and drop all points ' not close' to the line? Is that what you are attempting?

Comment: I added a picture to the post above, hopefully that will provide more clarity. They are faint moving asteroids in a set of 4 images. The asteroids should have at least 3 points along the same line, the noise, hot pixels, and cosmic rays will not have this feature. I'm trying to discard any set of only two points along the same line to clean up the plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an equation for the distance of one point from the line between two other points.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line).

```
def distance(point, segment):
    """Distance from a point to a line formed by a segment"""
    ...
```

Then loop through all the segments and calculate the distance from each point.  You will need a threshold for "close enough".  You could then make a list of all the points close to a line.  Something like this.

```
ON_LINE_THRESHOLD = 1.5

for segment in my_list:
    close_points = []
    for point1, point2 in my_list:
        if distance(point1, segment) < ON_LINE_THRESHOLD:
            close_points.append(point1)
        if distance(point2, segment) < ON_LINE_THRESHOLD:
            close_points.append(point2)
    if len(close_points) >=3:
        # Close points will always be at least two as it includes the end points.
        do something!
```

What you then do with the list of points on a line is up to you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot

Comment: I got it working with that approach. 1. Split all pairs out into a single list of points. 2. Ran every pair through the wiki distance-from-line formula against each single point in step 1. 3. Specify threshold for distance, save all new points to new list and plot. Thanks for putting me on the right track!